# CircleCI: why have two jobs: build and test that aren't DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, circleci-2.0

I was looking at [CircleCI's sample config for Ruby on Rails](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-ruby/#sample-configuration) which sets 2 jobs: build and test.

```yaml
version: 2.1 # Use 2.1 to enable using orbs and other features.

# Declare the orbs that we'll use in our config.
# read more about orbs: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/using-orbs/
orbs:
  ruby: circleci/ruby@1.0
  node: circleci/node@2

jobs:
  build: # our first job, named "build"
    docker:
      - image: cimg/ruby:2.7-node # use a tailored CircleCI docker image.
        auth:
          username: mydockerhub-user
          password: $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD  # context / project UI env-var reference
    steps:
      - checkout # pull down our git code.
      - ruby/install-deps # use the ruby orb to install dependencies
      # use the node orb to install our packages
      # specifying that we use `yarn` and to cache dependencies with `yarn.lock`
      # learn more: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/
      - node/install-packages:
          pkg-manager: yarn
          cache-key: "yarn.lock"

  test:  # our next job, called "test"
    # we run "parallel job containers" to enable speeding up our tests;
    # this splits our tests across multiple containers.
    parallelism: 3
    # here we set TWO docker images.
    docker:
      - image: cimg/ruby:2.7-node # this is our primary docker image, where step commands run.
        auth:
          username: mydockerhub-user
          password: $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD  # context / project UI env-var reference
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.5-alpine
        auth:
          username: mydockerhub-user
          password: $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD  # context / project UI env-var reference
        environment: # add POSTGRES environment variables.
          POSTGRES_USER: circleci-demo-ruby
          POSTGRES_DB: rails_blog_test
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
    # environment variables specific to Ruby/Rails, applied to the primary container.
    environment:
      BUNDLE_JOBS: "3"
      BUNDLE_RETRY: "3"
      PGHOST: 127.0.0.1
      PGUSER: circleci-demo-ruby
      PGPASSWORD: ""
      RAILS_ENV: test
    # A series of steps to run, some are similar to those in "build".
    steps:
      - checkout
      - ruby/install-deps
      - node/install-packages:
          pkg-manager: yarn
          cache-key: "yarn.lock"
      # Here we make sure that the secondary container boots
      # up before we run operations on the database.
      - run:
          name: Wait for DB
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:5432 -timeout 1m
      - run:
          name: Database setup
          command: bundle exec rails db:schema:load --trace
      # Run rspec in parallel
      - ruby/rspec-test

# We use workflows to orchestrate the jobs that we declared above.
workflows:
  version: 2
  build_and_test:     # The name of our workflow is "build_and_test"
    jobs:             # The list of jobs we run as part of this workflow.
      - build         # Run build first.
      - test:         # Then run test,
          requires:   # Test requires that build passes for it to run.
            - build   # Finally, run the build job.
```

The `test` job contains all the steps the `build` job does. So, what's the point of running the `build` job at all? It seems like extra steps to run this job every time.

I guess maybe this:

```yaml
steps:
      ...
      - checkout
      - ruby/install-deps
```

Would tell me if my codebase is bad before trying to run tests. But, wouldn't the test job fail at the same point before actually getting to running tests?

It seems to me like a waste of time to run the `build` job at all.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me like a waste of time to run the build job at all.

I guess the idea is that the test step is running in parallelism. If you run your build step first, it will update dependencies which then are cached for the three test steps. Otherwise each of your test steps would need to potentially update dependencies, so you end up with installing three times ruby, bundle, node etc which is a bit wasteful and these tasks are more likely to fail (as they rely on external resources). For the total build time it shouldn't make a difference if you run the bundle step or three times in parallel.

Comment: That could be the case but my few deploys so far don't seem to suggest this. I haven't seen where the cache is used for the test step, it could be a feature of the `ruby` orb I'm just not seeing in the interface.

Comment: I experimented with running this setup with the `build` job and without. I saved almost 2 minutes on average by removing `build`.